# nuget pack with symbols is missing "content" directory

Tags: nuget

I'm using nuget to package up some assemblies and additional files.

I need to keep the symbols separate, so I'm using "nuget pack -symbols" which creates two separate nupkg files.

The problem I have is that the .symbols.nupkg package only contains the "lib" directory (with PDBs and DLLs). It is missing "tools" and "content".

This means when someone installs the .symbols.nupkg, they don't get the extra files underneath "content". And because .symbols.nupkg has the exact same package id as the main .nupkg, nuget won't ever install the main package which does have "content" in it.

It's the same nuspec file which creates both packages, so I can't control it there.

Am I doing something wrong, or misunderstanding how the symbols package should be used?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is - *.symbols.pckg are meant to be kept on [www.symbolsource.org](http://www.symbolsource.org) ( or a local symbols feed)

**Sumbols.pckg does not replace a real package.** It's an addon.
Publish your package to nuget feed and symbol package to symbols feed.

But you actually can include pdb files in packet. Add this to nuspec file

```
 <files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\$id$.pdb" target="lib\net45\" />
 </files>
```